# public key encryption with java (encrypted string same length as original one)

Tags: java, string, security, encryption, rsa

I am trying to find a public key encryption method in java which will produce a string with the the same length as the original one. The usual rsa doesn't work. It produces a very long string for 3 character strings. What I want to do for my project is encrypt a string with a key then encrypt it again with a key but having a long string just slows down the process immensely. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no streaming cipher version of RSA that I know of (not possible what you suggest). It is not the length of the ciphertext that slows down the process, but RSA itself. So, you're actually more concerned about the performance and not about the length requirement?

Comment: More concerned about the length because sometimes I get an error - Data must not be longer than 256 bytes. Having a longer key will slow down a lot. Don't want to do it.

Comment: It is perfectly conceivable to create a stream cipher version of the RSA algorithm, but there is no Java implementation of it. The reason you get such a long string is because the Java implementation is a *block cipher*. The advantage of the long string is that it masks the relationship between the plaintext and the ciphertext.

Comment: @christopher But how? If I think about using CTR mode (a common way to make a stream cipher out of a block cipher), then the cipher is instantly broken, because the counter is encrypted with the public key.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Hmm.. it's a good point. I'd have to have more of a think about it but there's no immediate solution that presents itself to me.

Answer (score 2):

RSA doesn't have a streaming cipher mode which could create ciphertexts of the same length as the plaintexts. The ciphertext will always be the size of the modulus. So if you're using RSA 2048, the ciphertext will be 256 bytes long. There is no way to make it shorter. This will be exactly your requirement of 256 bytes, but if you also need to encode it for persistence of transmission then it will be bigger.

You could use a shorter RSA keys such as RSA 1536 which will result in 192 bytes ciphertext and if you would encode it with Base 64 it will be exactly 256 bytes long.

Comment: Happy to +1 this until I can think of a rebuttal!

Comment: @christopher I'm looking forward to it.